# Bluetooth not working for Ubuntu 22.10, HP Envy x360

Tags: bluetooth, 22.10

Recently installed Linux 22.10 on my laptop, and I'm having an error with blue-tooth that won't allow me to enable it.

I'm met with the error, "blue-tooth hci0 0pcode 0x c03 failed -110", when I start up Ubuntu.

Anyone face this issue before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the very informative description of the problem here
[Bluetooth not working - Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705772/bluetooth-not-working-debian/705798#705798)

Following the most important part:

> The device manufacturer (Foxconn) has replaced the Bluetooth chip
> manufacturer's USB vendor/product ID code with their own, your Linux
> kernel version cannot identify this Bluetooth chip by exact chip type.

The relevant addition of the IDs apparently didn't make it into kernel version 6.0 but only in 6.1.

So if you feel courageous (or are very impatient) you can install the 6.1 kernel from the "Ubuntu mainline kernel" of the 6.1 release. Currently Ubuntu 22.10 has 5.19.0-26
(to check your kernel version use: `uname -sr` in the console)

Sadly -- at the time of writing -- only the non-final version "v6.1-rc5" is available i.e. version 6.1 of the "Ubuntu-edition" of the kernel is not yet fully ready.

[Ubuntu Mainline kernels by the Ubuntu Kernel Team](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

After testing with this kernel version the bluetooth on my Envy x360 worked without a hitch.